# Importing Google Maps Polygon Extension

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to import a polygon extension into my React project and I'm unsure how to go about this.

This is what I'm looking at: https://github.com/openplacedatabase/gmaps-large-polygons

I'm not sure how to do this, I've imported the .js file containing the polygon prototype extension into my project and added a line to my index.html **before** importing Google Maps.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../utils/gmaps-large-polygons/gmaps-large-polygons.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%REACT_APP_G_MAP_API%&libraries=geometry,visualization,places,drawing,directions"></script>
```

I've tried to use the new options when creating a polygon like `lineSize` for example, but it does not seem to be working.

I guess there must be some more steps I don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. import the Google Maps Javascript API v3 **first** (so polygon is defined and can be extended)
2. import the `gmaps-large-polygons` script

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg&v=weekly&channel=2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openplacedatabase/gmaps-large-polygons@master/gmaps-large-polygon.js"></script>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0h69j5rq/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var poly;
// This example is the demo from https://github.com/openplacedatabase/gmaps-large-polygons
function initMap() {
  /**
   * http://stackoverflow.com/a/6339384/879121
   */
  google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds = function() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var paths = this.getPaths();
    var path;
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.getLength(); i++) {
      path = paths.getAt(i);
      for (var ii = 0; ii < path.getLength(); ii++) {
        bounds.extend(path.getAt(ii));
      }
    }
    return bounds;
  };
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(20, -10),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var shapeStyle = {
    "strokeColor": "#428bca",
    "strokeOpacity": 1,
    "strokeWeight": 3,
    "fillColor": "#9999ff",
    "fillOpacity": 0.3,
    editable: true,
    highlightColor: '#111111'
  };


  // Create map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  //
  // Setup polygon
  //

  // Create a polygon with a lot of points and add it to the map
  poly = google.maps.geojson.from(geojsonPolygon);
  poly.setMap(map);
  poly.setOptions(shapeStyle);
  map.fitBounds(poly.getBounds());

  // Make the polygon editable when clicked


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
var geojsonPolygon = {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [-87.71570900046997,
        33.00682400017906
      ],
/* snip so fit in code snippet */
      [-87.83205499982405,
        32.76975599977849
      ],
      [-87.8308639998843,
        32.76963799981476
      ],
      [-87.830633000212,
        32.76961700016936
      ],
      [-87.83020500023788,
        32.76957799987701
      ],
      [-87.8285420005035,
        32.768902999699705
      ],
      [-87.82809699992815,
        32.76872100038072
      ],
      [-87.82586399971979,
        32.76760800015759
      ],
      [-87.82531199994148,
        32.76733300039403
      ],
      [-87.82512100027712,
        32.76720999973664
      ],
      [-87.82474599961421,
        32.76695199994133
      ],
      [-87.82447100018686,
        32.76676699986933
      ],
      [-87.82317599986355,
        32.76589500033653
      ],
      [-87.82101100011603,
        32.763795999921896
      ],
      [-87.81651100016283,
        32.75942800023396
      ],
      [-87.81604499980914,
        32.75902199973601
      ],
      [-87.81538000013052,
        32.75844000040231
      ],
      [-87.81471500019546,
        32.75785900000458
      ],
      [-87.81444500020118,
        32.75762099989485
      ],
      [-87.81417399974622,
        32.757384999743635
      ],
      [-87.8123259996751,
        32.75577099978005
      ],
      [-87.80921399979633,
        32.753154000321935
      ],
      [-87.80911399972612,
        32.753069999896475
      ],
      [-87.80901300002292,
        32.75298499961307
      ],
      [-87.80828399988305,
        32.75237200015667
      ],
      [-87.80725500046118,
        32.75130599967815
      ],
      [-87.80651199996353,
        32.75013099979255
      ],
      [-87.8053010000872,
        32.74784400019017
      ],
      [-87.80429899960293,
        32.74554999970874
      ],
      [-87.80407099975815,
        32.74482700001399
      ],
      [-87.80434100044876,
        32.74292800003545
      ],
      [-87.80642999970335,
        32.73739499991951
      ],
      [-87.80670899975426,
        32.73619000022151
      ],
      [-87.80707099995972,
        32.734791999730405
      ],
      [-87.80732100031263,
        32.73407099968153
      ],
      [-87.80741099962275,
        32.733811999930865
      ],
      [-87.80751700057645,
        32.73371999959244
      ],
      [-87.80818299974251,
        32.73314200004328
      ],
      [-87.80954299952616,
        32.73304399955072
      ],
      [-87.811262999992,
        32.73328600034727
      ],
      [-87.81314899974436,
        32.733550000186405
      ],
      [-87.81556199948278,
        32.733841000379115
      ],
      [-87.81674400040832,
        32.73398300025539
      ],
      [-87.81734499995684,
        32.733966000148676
      ],
      [-87.81794600006495,
        32.733950000141256
      ],
      [-87.81830499996295,
        32.73393899986803
      ],
/* snip so fit in code snippet */      
      [-87.75765499970949,
        32.65400400025389
      ],
      [-87.75583599967838,
        32.65541199985393
      ],
      [-87.7544120002153,
        32.65708900037058
      ],
      [-87.75301199956941,
        32.65880400035218
      ],
      [-87.75280900048948,
        32.6590519999652
      ],
      [-87.75231900015659,
        32.659396000326346
      ],
      [-87.75213500038586,
        32.65941899972055
      ],
      [-87.75155899945217,
        32.65949200023593
      ],
      [-87.75054099975158,
        32.65943900038774
      ],
      [-87.75001000042319,
        32.65941400028267
      ],
      [-87.74910700049105,
        32.658797000434056
      ],
      [-87.74789000049833,
        32.65810099974256
      ],
      [-87.74615099990197,
        32.65713600032511
      ],
      [-87.74483299982127,
        32.65594599984789
      ],
      [-87.7437830001953,
        32.65435200046195
      ],
      [-87.74317400013099,
        32.65243699999335
      ],
      [-87.74315799994416,
        32.651742999920934
      ],
      [-87.74416099965342,
        32.64773299985494
      ],
      [-87.7445779998169,
        32.64677199988005
      ],
      [-87.74467599964328,
        32.64654599963073
      ],
      [-87.74477500034962,
        32.646319000333456
      ],
      [-87.74480899947017,
        32.64624200003082
      ],
      [-87.74490900023767,
        32.64601100030698
      ],
      [-87.74500900042378,
        32.645780000409054
      ],
      [-87.74538699994211,
        32.64491000043908
      ],
      [-87.7456525992338,
        32.644488905342534
      ],
      [-87.74608900038015,
        32.64379700016904
      ],
      [-87.74625499966338,
        32.64354100016055
      ],
      [-87.7465189995133,
        32.64313399986706
      ],
      [-87.74678199986698,
        32.64272600007504
      ],
      [-87.74694399993967,
        32.64247600007219
      ],
      [-87.74723800030466,
        32.64200600015605
      ],
      [-87.74798200028742,
        32.64081699993649
      ],
      [-87.74869300040613,
        32.63963200010213
      ],
      [-87.74931799984174,
        32.63870500038779
      ],
      [-87.74947999945546,
        32.63841000024515
      ],
      [-87.74971500028688,
        32.63798500015512
      ],
      [-87.74995000041157,
        32.63755899958572
      ],
      [-87.74998000025501,
        32.637504000364736
      ],
      [-87.75000999981965,
        32.6374480003805
      ],
      [-87.75059400050685,
        32.63670800005353
      ],
      [-87.75117899981103,
        32.63596700018743
      ],
      [-87.75205699980991,
        32.63485499961568
      ],
      [-87.7529350000355,
        32.63374300016463
      ],
      [-87.75306099992152,
        32.633583000034676
      ],
      [-87.75373299957329,
        32.6333409998383
      ],
      [-87.75471300037613,
        32.63336199996845
      ],
      [-87.75564900049507,
        32.63369799980667
      ],
      [-87.76290300049492,
        32.636395000189125
      ],
      [-87.76569300044267,
        32.63813699959848
      ],
      [-87.76923299992853,
        32.63982299978322
      ],
      [-87.77380299966116,
        32.64170499963842
      ],
      [-87.77490799965494,
        32.64179600016005
      ],
      [-87.77630400037611,
        32.64159499980391
      ],
      [-87.77818400022585,
        32.64093500011096
      ],
      [-87.77837100011087,
        32.640868999582004
      ],
      [-87.77855900015739,
        32.64080300021816
      ],
      [-87.77867800038428,
        32.64075999984429
      ],
      [-87.77879799960249,
        32.640717999624265
      ],
      [-87.77937599963221,
        32.640514999962186
      ],
      [-87.77995400034239,
        32.64031300005776
      ],
      [-87.78029399953311,
        32.6401940003963
      ],
      [-87.78063400019411,
        32.6400740000741
      ],
      [-87.78163100024317,
        32.63972399992519
      ],
      [-87.78199499988308,
        32.63959599982514
      ],
      [-87.78262799954938,
        32.63937299971171
      ],
      [-87.78283700008154,
        32.63930100019114
      ],
      [-87.78324800017607,
        32.63920399964375
      ],
      [-87.7833970004723,
        32.63916900005259
      ],
      [-87.78354399945756,
        32.63913400007181
      ],
      [-87.78484199949368,
        32.63882700037365
      ],
      [-87.78613900030146,
        32.63852000039503
      ],
      [-87.78746400020542,
        32.638206999586366
      ],
      [-87.78960100012813,
        32.63785199994343
      ],
      [-87.78964800031532,
        32.63784400028408
      ],
      [-87.79024399985028,
        32.637744999582296
      ],
      [-87.79083800034319,
        32.63764700022929
      ],
      [-87.79085099972016,
        32.63764500001907
      ],
      [-87.79104100046837,
        32.63761300013881
      ],
      [-87.7912289997037,
        32.63758199966167
      ],
      [-87.79124499987618,
        32.63757900008125
      ],
      [-87.79152199987207,
        32.63753199992301
      ],
      [-87.7917940004031,
        32.63748700017701
      ],
      [-87.79188999987261,
        32.637470999876086
      ],
      [-87.79255200028018,
        32.63736100019585
      ],
      [-87.79304400030485,
        32.63737200021028
      ],
      [-87.79305799971046,
        32.63737199976539
      ],
      [-87.79399399974783,
        32.63739600002293
      ],
      [-87.79492999961083,
        32.63741999971425
      ],
      [-87.79496499987839,
        32.63742100018533
      ],
      [-87.7972989998378,
        32.63747800001555
      ],
      [-87.80067099979337,
        32.637825000125105
      ],
      [-87.80348999946524,
        32.63776000006337
      ],
      [-87.80363000020596,
        32.63775699994694
      ],
      [-87.8037710003946,
        32.63775399994533
      ],
      [-87.8043890002605,
        32.63773999972145
      ],
      [-87.8077680000098,
        32.63798200036608
      ],
      [-87.80942899989908,
        32.63844599976793
      ],
      [-87.81011800038851,
        32.63817599980049
      ],
      [-87.81021399971384,
        32.63813700015482
      ],
      [-87.81029300032085,
        32.63805299968207
      ],
      [-87.81053199989321,
        32.63779399986768
      ],
      [-87.81077199949964,
        32.63753499982235
      ],
      [-87.81119200027973,
        32.63708199970983
      ],
      [-87.81161200034192,
        32.63663100026363
      ],
      [-87.81164299946546,
        32.63659800022752
      ],
      [-87.81182600011093,
        32.636308000061916
      ],
      [-87.81227600040745,
        32.63561300036989
      ],
      [-87.81272600012582,
        32.63491800044168
      ],
      [-87.81340100012703,
        32.63387499964957
      ],
      [-87.81337099989322,
        32.63303500000622
      ],
      [-87.81332699989366,
        32.63292499956406
      ],
      [-87.8132659996678,
        32.63277300036689
      ],
      [-87.81320499971031,
        32.63262000041888
      ],
      [-87.81274199961568,
        32.63146199974547
      ],
      [-87.81200199995088,
        32.630436000368604
      ],
      [-87.81083400019473,
        32.62881599970831
      ],
      [-87.80891899953525,
        32.62710499991795
      ],
      [-87.80826699970142,
        32.626015999917016
      ],
      [-87.80802799957688,
        32.62513300028531
      ],
      [-87.80775200009656,
        32.622312999984
      ],
      [-87.80750499973502,
        32.62129400035338
      ],
      [-87.80735699974467,
        32.62068300019218
      ],
      [-87.80675300014678,
        32.61928700024607
      ],
      [-87.80442900049195,
        32.6164839996128
      ],
      [-87.80143800046204,
        32.613432999647166
      ],
      [-87.79843599957003,
        32.6104469998922
      ],
      [-87.79704900050626,
        32.60961299981022
      ],
      [-87.7964320004202,
        32.60924300022081
      ],
      [-87.79572400003444,
        32.60891900013077
      ],
      [-87.79495999944558,
        32.608569000307185
      ],
      [-87.79419300038279,
        32.60821799991501
      ],
      [-87.79417000013103,
        32.6082069996828
      ],
      [-87.794032999462,
        32.608164000407605
      ],
      [-87.79259799997406,
        32.60770399977989
      ],
      [-87.79114199996442,
        32.607240999826836
      ],
      [-87.79093100047821,
        32.60716899991042
      ],
      [-87.7907259999825,
        32.60710299957984
      ],
      [-87.78950700035247,
        32.60671300006783
      ],
      [-87.78878100008956,
        32.606444000381856
      ],
      [-87.78822699964478,
        32.60623899958428
      ],
      [-87.78767099973224,
        32.606031999653574
      ],
      [-87.78762099982663,
        32.606014999842806
      ],
      [-87.78724999962238,
        32.60587699995636
      ],
      [-87.78687800039725,
        32.605739000100165
      ],
      [-87.78676600041744,
        32.60569700020314
      ],
      [-87.7866530000644,
        32.605656000401865
      ],
      [-87.78561499959663,
        32.60527199989833
      ],
      [-87.78456599981854,
        32.605049000239575
      ],
      [-87.783930999768,
        32.60513900000557
      ],
      [-87.78368999976696,
        32.60517300004584
      ],
      [-87.78344999999356,
        32.6052060002845
      ],
      [-87.78327100042944,
        32.60523099975866
      ],
      [-87.78303899995325,
        32.60534800021888
      ],
      [-87.7823800004109,
        32.60568200005899
      ],
      [-87.78171900025124,
        32.6060180002615
      ],
      [-87.7807770002937,
        32.60649900042521
      ],
      [-87.77678799948126,
        32.607988999883524
      ],
      [-87.77380700002077,
        32.60876500002242
      ],
      [-87.77367300009604,
        32.60878300023979
      ],
      [-87.77109199961123,
        32.60913599957639
      ],
      [-87.768814999614,
        32.60963699988253
      ],
      [-87.767312999701,
        32.61051999974514
      ],
      [-87.76700700053549,
        32.61069999994026
      ],
      [-87.76507999993886,
        32.611721999826344
      ],
      [-87.7635230004629,
        32.61254400038951
      ],
      [-87.76259400007433,
        32.61284099997004
      ],
      [-87.76241999975562,
        32.612895999746684
      ],
      [-87.7601510002289,
        32.613619000238515
      ],
      [-87.7599759998112,
        32.6136540002568
      ],
      [-87.75673000053195,
        32.614308999841626
      ],
      [-87.75661299946415,
        32.61432500017049
      ],
      [-87.75622399998312,
        32.61434800017994
      ],
      [-87.75582399985906,
        32.61436799976028
      ],
      [-87.75501599953778,
        32.614409000080705
      ],
      [-87.75412900017625,
        32.614453999769154
      ],
      [-87.75259700007595,
        32.61430799964524
      ],
      [-87.75215499969215,
        32.614265999634
      ],
      [-87.75179399986875,
        32.61421000022443
      ],
      [-87.75157399966103,
        32.61417599999126
      ],
      [-87.75124300051276,
        32.614126999627025
      ],
      [-87.75091399975204,
        32.614076999903965
      ],
      [-87.75069400044146,
        32.61404399964045
      ],
      [-87.75055799953847,
        32.614024000073826
      ],
      [-87.7503520000532,
        32.613993000386074
      ],
      [-87.75014699964872,
        32.61396100029381
      ],
      [-87.7500099994434,
        32.613940000307046
      ],
      [-87.74993299953691,
        32.61388100041255
      ],
      [-87.74947399991392,
        32.61352599955067
      ],
      [-87.74914400032429,
        32.613292999798915
      ],
      [-87.74900799990189,
        32.61319599991977
      ],
      [-87.74872299995617,
        32.61281599959827
      ],
      [-87.74871599979572,
        32.61275499961563
      ],
      [-87.748685000374,
        32.61249300035157
      ],
      [-87.7488380000892,
        32.61190200010822
      ],
      [-87.74880100020705,
        32.61118500039227
      ],
      [-87.74866600003872,
        32.61078000030628
      ],
      [-87.74850800054772,
        32.61030399989787
      ],
      [-87.74817300008237,
        32.609087999725986
      ],
      [-87.74732300026649,
        32.60712900002935
      ],
      [-87.74702900000284,
        32.60647800018721
      ],
      [-87.74691400050799,
        32.60622300014419
      ],
      [-87.7467990001023,
        32.60597000043332
      ],
      [-87.74656600030124,
        32.605453999703556
      ],
      [-87.74633300032662,
        32.604939000419904
      ],
      [-87.74625999951398,
        32.604778000197655
      ],
      [-87.74597499987506,
        32.604111999730236
      ],
      [-87.74591199997724,
        32.60396599975714
      ],
      [-87.74584900003303,
        32.6038189998028
      ],
      [-87.74553999991784,
        32.60309799972407
      ],
      [-87.74545399986363,
        32.60288800032072
      ],
      [-87.74470500003746,
        32.601070000091404
      ],
      [-87.74418499991806,
        32.59910599956559
      ],
      [-87.74401799981898,
        32.59868899970994
      ],
      [-87.74359700000814,
        32.597636999974206
      ],
      [-87.74344300007687,
        32.597437000371556
      ],
      [-87.74338799981639,
        32.597367000147194
      ],
      [-87.74333500011866,
        32.597297999817954
      ],
      [-87.74319000036711,
        32.59711200010883
      ],
      [-87.7430480002025,
        32.596928999790016
      ],

      // snip so fits in code snippet
      [-87.71570900046997,
        33.00682400017906
      ]
    ]
  ]
};
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Polygon</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openplacedatabase/gmaps-large-polygons@master/gmaps-large-polygon.js"></script>
  <script src='https://rawgithub.com/openplacedatabase/geojson-google-maps/master/geojson-google-maps.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```